# Remove all anchor tags and anything inside them in mysql

Tags: html, mysql, sql, regex, tags

I'm very new to **SQL** and need to remove several hundred links from specific **MySQL** databases. I got a working **REGEXP** to find those entries however I can't get it to work with **UPDATE** query.

What is the best way to find and remove all anchor tags and their content in a **MySQL Database**?

**Example:**

```
Some text <a href="some-link.com">more text</a>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**Edit:**

The link is always the last entry so maybe you could find the beginning of an anchor tag and then delete everything from there? No idea how to do that though.

Comment: What is your mysql version ?

Comment: What is the  update query you tryed?

Comment: THe mysql version is 5.5.57 i believe

Comment: I tried something like this:
UPDATE table
SET column = REPLACE(column,'REGEXP', '') 
WHERE column like "REGEXP"

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
UPDATE yourTable SET yourcolumn= REPLACE(yourcolumn, '<yourHtmlTag>', '');
```

This will change this :

```
------------------
id|yourcolumn
--|---------------
1|1111mytag2222
2|2222mytag3333

To this :
------------------
id|yourcolumn
--|---------------
1|11112222
2|22223333
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer however this won't work because the links contain individual href's and maybe ID's and/or classes. Also this won't remove the link text.

Comment: Hello, can you please share some real rows from your database so i can try help you

Answer (score 0):

Some tags, such as B, I, SPAN, contain text that you want to keep?  Furthermore, these can be nested?

Some tags, such as BR, P, are "stand-alone".

Some tags, such as A, IMG, should have the contents removed?

You can have multiple tags in a text, correct?

Unless you are running MariaDB with its `REGEXP_REPLACE()`, you are best off doing your task in application code.

**Example with MySQL**

For a single occurrence of `... <a ...>...</a> ...` and removing the start and end tags:

1. `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` can locate `<`
2. locate the first `>` after that
3. do some sort of `MID()` or `LEFT`() to chop apart the line
4. Use `CONCAT()` to put the remain pieces together`
5. Repeat for the trailing `</a>`.

Comment: There is only plain text and one anchor tag at the end. A way to remove all tags or everything after a "<" would work.

Comment: OK, there are some hints.